# how to load JSON for this highchart - django app

Tags: json, django, highcharts

I am working on django project

I want to do a highchart dependency wheel but I don't know why the chart not showing , you will see my code below , 
in my **dependencywheel.html** I did already `{%load static%}` in the top ,

```
<script>
        Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Dependency Wheel'
        },

        accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. From {point.exped} to {point.destin}: {point.count}.'
        }
        },

        series: [{
        keys: ['exped', 'destin', 'count'],
        data: '{%url "data"%}',
        type: 'dependencywheel',
        name: 'Dependency wheel series',
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#333',
            textPath: {
            enabled: true,
            attributes: {
                dy: 5
            }
            },
            distance: 10
        },
        size: '95%'
        }]

        });

 </script>
```

that's my **views.py**

```
@login_required
def depend(request):
    return render(request,'dependWheel.html',{})

def jsonDepend(request):
     dataset = mail_item_countries_depend.objects.all().values_list('exped','destin','count')
     data = list(dataset)

     return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

the chart is not showing , how can I load my data

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the dependency wheel doesn't show , that's my problem

Comment: I was thinking that the problem is probably in the view function , I tried but can't solve it (

Comment: Can you open the console i.e. in the developer tools in your browser and see if there is any Javascript error there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's the answer:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.getJSON('data',function(data){
                Highcharts.chart('container', {

                title: {
                    text: 'Highcharts Dependency Wheel'
                },

                accessibility: {
                    point: {
                    valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. From {point.from} to {point.to}: {point.weight}.'
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
                    data:data,
                    type: 'dependencywheel',
                    name: 'Dependency wheel series',
                    dataLabels: {
                    color: '#333',
                    textPath: {
                        enabled: true,
                        attributes: {
                        dy: 5
                        }
                    },
                    distance: 10
                    },
                    size: '95%'
                }]

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```